# The array add on isn't carried through to the checkout

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Okay so if the customer selects 1 gift, 1 product and UK in the drop down menu the price adds up to £18.48 but when they type in a certain post code (listed in the array) it should add an extra £2.00 to the total making it £20.48 which it does. But when pressing checkout it only carries over the £18.48.... is this because the array is not added into the formula below for the total sum?

```
<script>
    function myFunction(pc) {
        var postcode_arr = ["ZE", "KW", "IV", "HS", "AB", "DD", "PH", "PA", "FK", "KY", "G", "BT", "IM", "GY", "JE", "EH", "ML", "KA"];
        var firsttwo = pc.substr(0, 2);
        firsttwo = firsttwo.toUpperCase();
        //alert(firsttwo);

        var a = postcode_arr.indexOf(firsttwo);
        if (a != -1) {
            var amt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value);
            amt += 2;
            document.getElementById("amount").value = amt;
        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
    }
</script>
<form action="https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method="post" name="BuyForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="instId" value="000000"><!-- The "instId" value "0000000" should be replaced with the Merchant's own installation Id -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="abc123"><!-- This is a unique identifier for merchants use. Example: PRODUCT123 -->
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP"><!-- Choose appropriate currency that you would like to use -->
    <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="testMode" value="100">

    <script language="JavaScript">

        // The next two functions round numbers to numerical formatting. They do not need to be altered when adding or removing products.
        function roundOff(value, precision) {
            return places(value, 1, precision);
        }

        function places(X, M, N) {
            var T, S = new String(Math.round(X * Number("1e" + N)))

            while (S.length < M + N) S = '0' + S
            var y = S.substr(0, T = (S.length - N));
            if (N > 0) {
                y += '.' + S.substr(T, N);
            }

            return y;
        }

        // This function checks for empty quantities. It does not need to be altered when adding or removing products.
        function CheckNull(value) {
            if (value == "") {
                value = "0";
            }

            return value;
        }

        // This function defines the postage and packaging location. It does not need to be altered when adding or removing products.
        function typeOfCarriage(x, whereabouts) {
            console.log(whereabouts);
            x.carriage_amount.value = whereabouts;
        }

        // This function addeds the postage and packaging to the total price of the products. Add new postage rates here, and also edit further down the page to add them to the table.
        function calculate(x) {
            basicprice = calc(x);
            if (Number(basicprice) > 0) {
                console.log(basicprice);

                switch (x.carriage_amount.value) {
                    case "UK":
                        postage_and_packaging = 3.50;
                        break
                    case "US":
                        postage_and_packaging = 20.38;
                        break
                        // To add a new postage rate. Copy from here...
                    case "asia":
                        postage_and_packaging = 5.75;
                        break
                        // ...to here, and paste directly below. Change the case country, and the postage price. You will also need to add the postage option you have created further down the page.
                    default:
                        postage_and_packaging = 8.75;
                        break;
                }
                x.amount.value = basicprice + Number(postage_and_packaging);

            }
            else {
                x.amount.value = "0";
            }

            x.amount.value = roundOff(x.amount.value, 2);
        }

        // The standard price, exluding postage and packaging is calculated here. It does not need to be altered when adding or removing products. -->
        function calc(x) {
            x.amount.value = 0;
            var y = x.price.length;
            var z = x.qty.length;
            var a = Number(x.amount.value);
            var b, c;

            while (y > 0) {
                b = Number(CheckNull(x.price[y - 1].value));
                c = Number(CheckNull(x.qty[y - 1].value));
                a += (b * c);
                y--;
            }
            return a;
        }
    </script>

    <h1>Postage &amp; Packaging</h1>

    <!-- This table provides layout for the products listed. -->
    <table cellpadding="3" border="2" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><b>Personal Message (Hand Written by Mr.F Himself)</b><input name="price" type="hidden" value="3.99"> - &pound;3.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quantity: <input name="qty" size="3" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><b>195 x 295 Pixboard</b><input name="price" type="hidden" value="10.99"> - &pound;10.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quantity: <input name="qty" size="3" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br><br>

    <div id="PM">
        <p> <b>Personal Message</b> </p>
        <p> (This will only be written if you've specified so above) </p>
        <p> You have a limit of 140 Characters </p>
        <input id="PMTB" type="text" rows="2" name="Personal Message" maxlength="140"><br>
    </div>

    <!-- This table is used as the total calculator and postage and packaging selector. -->
    <p>
        <div id="Select">
            <input name="carriage_amount" type="hidden" value="uk">
            <select name=postage_and_packaging onchange="typeOfCarriage(this.form,this.value);calculate(this.form)">
                <option selected value="">Please select country</option>

            </select>

    <p> <input name="calcButton" onclick="calculate(this.form)" type=button value="Calculate Total"> </p>
    <p>
        <b>Total: &pound; </b><input id="amount" name="amount" size=8 value="0">
    </p>

    </div>
    </p>
    <div id="Essentials">
        <p><b>Essentials</b></p>
        <table id="HV" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Free Pen" value="Free Pen"> Free Pen<br>

                    ( You will only recive this if Mr.F isnt writing your personal message )
                    <p></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Horizontal" value="Horizontal"> Horizontal<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    or
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Vertical" value="Vertical"> Vertical<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="PDF">

        <b>Delivery Details</b>
        <p>
            <label>Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Full Name" required>

        <p>
            <label>Mobile Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="Mobile Number">

        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Home Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="Home Phone" required>

        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" required>

        </p>

        <b>Home Address</b>
        <p>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="Address" required>
        <p>
            <label>Town</label>
            <input type="text" name="Town/City" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="Town/City" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Country</label>
            <input type="text" name="Country" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Post Code</b><input name="postcode" type="text" required onblur="myFunction(this.value);">
        <p>
        </p>

        <b>Business Address</b>
        <p>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="Address">
        <p>
            <label>Town</label>
            <input type="text" name="Town/City">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="Town/City">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Country</label>
            <input type="text" name="Country">
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Post Code</b><input name="postcode" type="text" onblur="myFunction(this.value);">
        <p>
        </p>



        <b>Gift Address</b>
        <p>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="Address">
        <p>
            <label>Town</label>
            <input type="text" name="Town/City">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="Town/City">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Country</label>
            <input type="text" name="Country">
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Post Code</b><input name="postcode" type="text" onblur="myFunction(this.value);">
        <p>
        </p>

    </div>
    <center>
        <p><b>Dont forget to upload your image</b></p>
    </center>

    <!-- This generates a button that submits the information and send the user into the Worldpay payment pages. -->
    <p align="center"><input type=submit value=Checkout onclick="calculate(this.form)"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to understand what's all going on here, but it seems that the `myFunction` only gets called on the blur of the postcode element. Meaning it has to be selected first, then deselected, which triggers the blur.
My guess is this trigger won't happen. So you have to make sure the `myFunction` gets called regardless, with the current value of the postcode input element.

Comment: Okay so would I have to change "blur" to something different?

Comment: No, I think it'd be better to just call the `myFunction` every time the page is loaded. So somewhere near the bottom of your code (just before the `</script>` should be fine) there's something like:
`myFunction( getElementById('postcode').value );`, obviously adding the postcode id to the input element first :).

Comment: wait so are you saying get red of the array or add this into the array?

Comment: No, I'm saying to read the currently set value from the postcode input element, and give it to your `myFunction`, so it'll add the 2 if need be. Normally it would do that automatically when you go through the form while filling it in, but what happens now is that the form is probably reset in some way and it doesn't automatically execute the onblur event.

Comment: sorry i'm still newish and learning...... any chance you could edit the code above with the information you've provided? I understand what you mean just have no idea where to add it into......

Comment: Do you mean like this?

Comment: <script>
function myFunction(postcode) {
    var postcode_arr = ["ZE", "KW","IV","HS","AB","DD","PH","PA","FK","KY","G","BT","IM","GY","JE","EH","ML","KA"];

    var firsttwo = pc.substr(0,2);
    firsttwo = firsttwo.toUpperCase();
    //alert(firsttwo);

    var a = postcode_arr.indexOf(firsttwo);
    if(a!= -1) {
        var amt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value);
        amt +=2;
        document.getElementById("amount").value = amt;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}

myFunction( getElementById('postcode').value );
</script>

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow again tomorrow, I'm quite busy right now. It would be really useful if you placed your code in a Codepen or similar though:
http://codepen.io/pen/
Then me and other people can simply edit that, to try and make it work.